# remove words from string by position php

Tags: php, string

I want to remove the words from a string by a given position from input, also the following words with the position from input.

EXAMPLE:

```
position = 2
```

string = `aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh`

Will become: `aa cc ee gg`

I have:

```
$delete = $position - 1;
$words = explode(" ", $string);
if(isset($words[$delete])) unset($words[$delete]);
$string = implode(" ", $words);
echo $string;}
```

That displays

```
aa cc dd ee ff gg hh
```

Comment: What is your question danr? The code seems to be working fine

Comment: I think he wants to remove every 2nd element after a deletion. The example removed more then just bb, it also removes dd and ff and hh.

Comment: yes, that is right Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $position = 2;

$string = 'aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh';

$arr=explode(' ', $string);
$final_str='';

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) {

    if($i%$position==0) {
    $final_str.=$arr[$i].' ';
    }

}

echo $final_str;
```

Comment: Did you test this? It doesn't adjust for $position being 1-based instead of 0-based.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but i think this is what you are looking for. 
This will remove every 2nd word after a deletion or when starting to count the words.

```
$deletePos = 2;
$words = explode(" ", $string);

$i = 1;
foreach($words as $key => $word) {
  if ($i == $deletePos) {
    unset($words[$key]);
    $i = 1;
    continue;
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$position = 2;
$string = 'aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh';
$arr=explode(' ', $string);
$count = count($arr);
// $position-1 because PHP arrays are 0-based, but the $position is 1-based.
for ($i = $position-1; $i < $count; $i += $position) {
  unset($arr[$i]);
}
$new_string = implode(' ', $arr);
echo $new_string;
```